# How can I animate the height of a CALayer with the origin coming from the bottom instead of the top?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I want to animate a simple CALayer to move up and down in response to incoming data (bars on a graphic equaliser)

The CALayer should remain *fixed* along the bottom and move up and down as the height is animated.

Can anybody advise on the best way to achieve this without having to animate the origin y coord as well as the height?

Answer (score 13):

If you want the layer to always grow and shrink from the bottom, then you should set your own `anchorPoint` on the layer that is the bottom. The anchor point is specified in the layers unit coordinate space so both X and Y range from 0 to 1 inside of the bounds, no matter the size.

```
yourLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
```

Then for the animation, you simply animate the bounds (or even better, you can animate `"bounds.size.height"`, since only the height is changing):

```
// set the new bounds of yourLayer here...

CABasicAnimation *grow = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size.height"];
grow.fromValue = @0;   // from no height
grow.toValue   = @200; // to a height of 200
grow.duration  = 0.5;
// add any additional animation configuration here...
[yourLayer addAnimation:grow forKey:@"grow the height of the layer"];
```

---

- You can read more about the anchor point in [this article I wrote a couple of years ago](http://blog.ideveloper.tv/understanding-the-anchor-point/).
- You can read more about the Key-Value Coding extensions for Core Animation [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html).

Comment: Unfortunately all I see when I try this approach is quivering bars (the height just seems to flutter). Could it be because I'm trying to perform 11 animations per second?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. But I can't know what is wrong unless you show me the code you are using